# Solve the equation by Jacobi's method : $5x + 2y +4z = 12$ ;$x+4y=2z=15$ ;$x+2y+5z=20$

Tags: numerical-methods

Solve the equation by Jacobi's method :
$$5x + 2y +7z = 30$$
$$x+4y+2z=15$$
$$x+2y+5z=20$$
I am getting the values as $$x=4.08,y=3.375,z=4.12.$$

My equations :
$$x=\frac{1}{5} \{30-2y-7z\}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{4} \{15-x-2z\}$$
$$z=\frac{1}{5} \{20-x-2y\}$$

The values are given to be :$$x=1,y=2,z=3$$
(apologies for the previous errors)

Comment: $1+4+2=7$ and $1+2+5=8$....

Comment: sorry too much errors have to delete

Comment: What are you using as the starting value?

Comment: itnitial values as zero

Comment: With a starting value of $x_0 = (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$, the Jacobi method converges to $x = (1, 2, 3)$ in 133 iterations (give or take depending on precision).

Comment: 133 iterations? i am told to do only 3 the how am i supposed to do this

Comment: Well, you pick $x_0 = (0, 0, 0)$ and use the iteration formula to calculate $x_1, x_2, x_3$ manually. It can be done by hand, but will not converge for a long while.